# How do I use a Chainlink api call to retrieve a string value from json returned by api

Tags: web3js, chainlink

I am trying to use a chainlink request to make an api call, then update the volume variable with the result of the api call.

The api call should retrieve a string. After deploying and funding the smart contract it seems I am able to make the api call successfully (although I'm not sure about this). The problem is the volume variable isn't updating.

I adapted the code from a [chainlink tutorial](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/). The original tutorial code works, to my mind the changes I made should also work. Can anyone help with this?

```
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

string public volume;

address private oracle;
bytes32 private jobId;
uint256 private fee;

/**
 * Network: Kovan
 * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
 * Node)
 * Job ID: d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747
 * Fee: 0.1 LINK
 */
constructor() {
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
    oracle = 0xF405B99ACa8578B9eb989ee2b69D518aaDb90c1F;
    jobId = "c51694e71fa94217b0f4a71b2a6b565a";
    fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
}

/**
 * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
 * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
 */
function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
{
    Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    
    // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
    request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    
    // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
    // {"RAW":
    //   {"ETH":
    //    {"USD":
    //     {
    //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
    //     }
    //    }
    //   }
    //  }
    request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.MARKET");
    
    // // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
    // int timesAmount = 10**18;
    // request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
    
    // Sends the request
    return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
}

/**
 * Receive the response in the form of uint256
 */ 
function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bytes32 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
{
    volume = bytes32ToString(_volume);
    
}


function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32) public pure returns (string memory) {
    uint8 i = 0;
    while(i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0) {
        i++;
    }
    bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(i);
    for (i = 0; i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0; i++) {
        bytesArray[i] = _bytes32[i];
    }
    return string(bytesArray);
}

// function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To return a string, you actually have to return a `bytes32` and cast it to a string on-chain.

You can use something like this, to turn a bytes32 to string:

```js
function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32) public pure returns (string memory) {
        uint8 i = 0;
        while(i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0) {
            i++;
        }
        bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(i);
        for (i = 0; i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0; i++) {
            bytesArray[i] = _bytes32[i];
        }
        return string(bytesArray);
    }
```